# Drop pandas column with constant alphanumeric values

Tags: pandas, alphanumeric, drop

I have a dataframe `df` that contains around 2 million records.
Some of the columns contain only alphanumeric values (e.g. "wer345", "gfer34", "123fdst").

Is there a pythonic way to drop those columns (e.g. using `isalnum()`)?

Comment: what is the type of object contained in the other columns you don't want to drop?

Comment: There are som special characters , such as "!-123!" or "asd!!!-23!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply [`Series.str.isalnum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isalnum.html) column-wise to mask all the alphanumeric values of the DataFrame. Then use [`DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) to find the columns that only contain alphanumeric values. Invert the resulting boolean Series to select only the columns that contain at least one non-alphanumeric value.

```
is_alnum_col = df.apply(lambda col: col.str.isalnum()).all()
res = df.loc[:, ~is_alnum_col]
```

---

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['aas', 'sd12', '1232'],
    'b': ['sdds', 'nnm!!', 'ab-2'],
    'c': ['sdsd', 'asaas12', '12.34'],
})

is_alnum_col = df.apply(lambda col: col.str.isalnum()).all()
res = df.loc[:, ~is_alnum_col]
```

Output:

```
>>> df

      a      b        c
0   aas   sdds     sdsd
1  sd12  nnm!!  asaas12
2  1232   ab-2    12.34

>>> df.apply(lambda col: col.str.isalnum())

      a      b      c
0  True   True   True
1  True  False   True
2  True  False  False

>>> is_alnum_col

a     True
b    False
c    False
dtype: bool

>>> res

       b        c
0   sdds     sdsd
1  nnm!!  asaas12
2   ab-2    12.34
```

Comment: Would this error if you have all columns that have only strings or numbers? Thinking something like: `try:
  X_train.sample(10000).apply(lambda col: col.str.isalnum()).all()
except:
  print('no alphanumeric columns')` ?